# Meteor's reactivity rerendering everything

Tags: meteor, rendering

I am working on Meteor app. I have this in the main template:

```
{{# if currentUser}}
    {{> app}}
{{else}}
    {{> login }}
{{/if}}
```

This shows login page when user is not logged in and app page otherwise.

Then in my code I simply update current user:

```
Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), {$set: {event_id: 1}});
```

The problem is that this causes everything to be rerendered, since current user has changed.   This is a big problem by itself. But what's even worse is that I am using Bootstrap modal which must not be rerendered (bootstrap keeps javascript references to the dom elements)

How can I make app rerender only when (currentUser == null) changes it's value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a separate collection to keep track of the user information, so you never query on the user collection itself. This problem should be fixed with Meteor UI whenever it lands. You can try it out now by running Meteor with `meteor --release template-engine-preview-5.5`.

Comment: I already found out about the new template engine and it works great. Is there any expected date when it will be released?

Comment: Yes, along with Meteor 1.0 in early 2014. Could be later; the original 1.0 expected date was late 2013.

Answer (score 2):

How about making a variable taken from [`Meteor.userId()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_userid)?

```
Template.yourTemplate.isLoggedIn = function(){
  return !!Meteor.userId();
}
```

Your template should be like this now:

```
{{#if isLoggedIn}}
    {{> app}}
{{else}}
    {{> login }}
{{/if}}
```

Comment: The problem is that Meteor.userId() is also reactive and still causes template to rerender (even if !!Meteor.userId() doesn't change value)

Comment: kustrie, this solution works for me.  I tested with a bit of code I put up at http://overly-sensitive-current-user.meteor.com/. Login and change the userprofile (Meteor.users.update({_id:Meteor.userId()}, {$set:{'profile':{'key':'value1'}}})) and note that the app template is not re-rendered. Maybe there's something else in your code that is causing the re-render.  Gist is here: https://gist.github.com/jrullmann/7848364

Answer (score 1):

```
Template.main.userLoggedIn = function () {
  return ! Session.equals(Meteor.user(), null);
};
```

This exemplifies one of the benefits of Session.equals relative to Session.get with respect to triggering invalidations.